# How to make cross page reference work in Hugo?

Tags: hugo

I have a hugo project setup based on [this](https://github.com/devcows/hugo-universal-theme) theme and have the below project structure.

```
content
    learning
        aws
            index.md
            how-we-use
                index.md
```

Inside the `aws > index.md` file, I want to have a link which opens up `how-we-use > index.md`. I tried below (and a lot other things), but every time I click it, it give me 404.

Tried below in `aws > index.md`.

```
- [How we use AWS](./how-we-use)
- [How we use AWS](/how-we-use)
- [How we use AWS](/learning/aws/how-we-use)
```

Below is my `how-we-use > index.md`

```
+++
title = "How we use AWS"
aliases = "/learning/aws/how-we-use/"
+++

Hi There
```

Also, tried changing this alias to `/how-we-use/` and `/how-we-use` but still doesn't work.

config.toml

```
baseurl = "https://welcome-page" 
title = "welcome"
theme = "hugo-universal-theme"
themesDir = "./themes"
languageCode = "en-us"
uglyURLs = false
# Site language. Available translations in the theme's `/i18n` directory.
defaultContentLanguage = "en"

# Define the number of posts per page
paginate = 10

# not pluralize title pages by default
pluralizelisttitles = false

[[menu.main]]
    name       = "Learnings"
    identifier = "menu.learnings"
    url        = "/img/learnings.png"
    weight     = 4

[[menu.main]]
    name       = "Learnings"
    identifier = "section.learnings"
    url        = ""
    weight     = 1
    parent     = "menu.learnings"
    post       = 1


[[menu.main]]
    name       = "AWS"
    identifier = "learning.aws"
    url        = "/aws"
    weight     = 1
    parent     = "section.learnings"
```

How to get this cross reference to work ?

p.s - if I change the name of the files to `_index.md`, then no content is displayed and I just see the title getting displayed but nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

md link format `[]()` could be used with full link `[](https://...)` or with anchor `[](#anchor)`, but you need relative link and hugo has another syntax for it: `[]({{< ref "" >}})`

According to [Hugo documentation](https://gohugo.io/content-management/cross-references/) index.md can be reference either by its path or by its containing folder without the ending /. _index.md can be referenced only by its containing folder.

So try it:

- `[How we use AWS]({{< ref "/how-we-use" >}})`

It works with my ananke theme. But you could try also:

- `[How we use AWS]({{< ref "/how-we-use/index" >}})`
- `[How we use AWS]({{< ref "/learning/aws/how-we-use" >}})`
- `[How we use AWS]({{< ref "/learning/aws/how-we-use/index" >}})`